# Dart: convert map into query string

Tags: url, dictionary, type-conversion, query-string, dart

I have a situation where I need to turn a `Map` into a query String (after the first `?`). For instance if I have the following map:

```dart
Map json = {
    "email":  eml,
    "password": passwd
};
```

And a base URL:

```dart
String baseURL = "http://localhost:8080/myapp";
```

Then I need something that converts the json `Map` into the query string of the base URL:

```dart
String fullURL = parameterizeURL(baseURL, json);

// Prints: http://localhost:8080/myapp?email=blah&password=meh
// (if "blah" was entered as the email, and "meh" was entered as the password)
print(fullURL);
```

I found [this query String-to-map library](https://github.com/kaisellgren/QueryString) on Git, but I need the **inverse** of this! It would be great to get URL encoding in there as well.

**I'm happy to make something homegrown but being so new to Dart I was wondering if there's anything on `pub`/Github/the etherspehere that does this already.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you describe your usage a bit? First off, keeping data such as password in a GET request is not good practice. This is something that would better off being a POST request. That said, if you do want to use it as a POST request to send the map the server, take a look at: [HttpRequest.postFormData](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/dev/latest/dart_html/HttpRequest.html#postFormData) it will automatically add the Map you provide as the POST data to the server. One caveat to remember is that data must be a Map (or keys and values must be strings). Example usage:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
// ...

// Somewhere in your login related method
HttpRequest.postFormData('login.php', data).then((HttpRequest req) {
  if(req.status != 200) {
    print(req.statusText);
  }
});
```

There is a package available for server-side Dart which allows you to easily compose hand deal with various HTTP request, aptly named [http](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http). However this does not work with Client side scripts. I'm not aware of any existing packages which would provide the functionality you're looking for.

On that note, if you do decide to roll your own, perhaps provide a pull request to the QueryString project you mentioned in your question so that functionality can become available to others in one simple package.

Comment: Thanks @Matt B (+1) - I guess the email/password is a bad use case. Say I wanted to construct a URL for hitting a 3rd party RESTful API at a GET endpoint, say: `(GET) http://api.somevendor.example.com/widgets?fragile=true&size=4&color=red`. In that case, I'd like something that converts a `Map params = { "fragile": true, "size": 4, "color": "red" };` into the URL. Again, I'm happy to do this myself, but before I exert the mental energy, was wondering if Dart has anything that already does this - no sense to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Updated my response for serverside. But ultimately no I'm not aware of an existing package which provides that functionality on client-side.

Comment: This is not the answer to asked question even though it's a legitimate answer.

Answer (score 30):

TL;DR

```dart
String queryString = Uri(queryParameters: {'x': '1', 'y': '2'}).query;

print(queryString); // x=1&y=2
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `queryParameters` can only be a `Map<String, String>` or `Map<String, Iterable<String>>`. Unfortunately, it is not intelligent enough to automatically `.toString()` values of a `Map<String, dynamic>` type.
https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/Uri/Uri.html

The following logic converts my dynamic map for my use:
`Uri(queryParameters: json.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value == null ? null : value.toString()))).query`

Answer (score 27):

Have you looked at the Uri class in dart:core. You can construct a Uri class from Url components :

```dart
new Uri({String scheme, String userInfo: "", String host: "", port: 0, String path, 
  Iterable<String> pathSegments, String query, 
  Map<String, String> queryParameters, fragment: ""}) #
```

Notice you pass the query string as a map, if you are using a HTTP client that doesn't take this class you can .toString it to get the Url.

I use this in my code rather than string Url's

As an example using your data above :

```dart
void main() {

      String eml = "me@here.com";
      String passwd = "password";

      Map json = {
                  "email":  eml,
                  "password": passwd
      };  


      Uri outgoingUri = new Uri(scheme: 'http',
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 8080,
          path: 'myapp',
          queryParameters:json);

      print(outgoingUri);

    }
```

This prints :

```dart
http://localhost:8080/myapp?email=me%40here.com&password=password
```

Note that once constructed a Uri is immutable, i.e. you can't change the query parameters again. There is also [this](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/uri) package in pub which may give more facilities although I've not used it yet.

Comment: Thanks @user2685314 (+1) - can you show me an actual code example, perhaps using my email/password example above? Thanks again!!!

Comment: Why isn't this the accepted answer? You can also use the `Uri` constructor with just the `queryParameters` parameters to convert a `Map` into a query string, which is very convenient.

Comment: it doesn't convert non-String values like int or bool

Answer (score 7):

```dart
final yourMap = {'x': '1', 'y': '2'};
final queryString = yourMap.toMap().entries.map((e) => '${e.key}=${e.value}').join('&');
print(queryString); // x=1&y=2
```

Answer (score 4):

i wrote a recursive function to turn any `Map<String, dynamic>` to query `String`.

```
String getQueryString(Map params, {String prefix: '&', bool inRecursion: false}) {

    String query = '';

    params.forEach((key, value) {

        if (inRecursion) {
            key = '[$key]';
        }

        if (value is String || value is int || value is double || value is bool) {
            query += '$prefix$key=$value';
        } else if (value is List || value is Map) {
            if (value is List) value = value.asMap();
            value.forEach((k, v) {
                query += getQueryString({k: v}, prefix: '$prefix$key', inRecursion: true);
            });
        }
   });

   return query;
}
```

example:

```
Map<String, dynamic> params = {'aa': 1.1, 'bb': [2, [3, ['5', {'66': 777}]]]};
String query = getQueryString(params);
print(query);
```

this code will print:

```
&aa=1.1&bb[0]=2&bb[1][0]=3&bb[1][1][0]=5&bb[1][1][1][66]=777
```

Comment: like? i used the most reasonable types that you will send as a query parameter.

Comment: print(Uri(queryParameters: {'name': 'John Deo', 'age': '25'}).query);

Comment: this is the hackiest of all

Answer (score 2):

Just in case if you use the Dio library, you might use Transformer.urlEncodeMap. It accepts Map<String, dynamic>

```
String Transformer.urlEncodeMap(Map<String, dynamic>)
```

You can find it in the official docs here: https://pub.dev/documentation/dio/latest/dio/Transformer/urlEncodeMap.html

Answer (score 2):

I think that the easiest way to to generate a query string from a `Map` is to use [`Uri.replace`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Uri/replace.html).  It's basically the same thing as using the [`Uri` constructor](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Uri/Uri.html), but it avoids needing to manually copy all of the other parts of the URL:

```dart
String baseURL = "http://localhost:8080/myapp";

Map json = {
  "email":  eml,
  "password": passwd
};

String fullURL = Uri.parse(baseURL).replace(queryParameters: json).toString();
```

I realize that I'm responding to an old question, but I feel compelled to additionally point out that you probably shouldn't be sending passwords via query strings.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and wrote this function for me. Here it is in case someone needs it:

```dart
String makeQuery(Map<String, dynamic>? data) {
  var result = [];

  if (data != null) {
    data.forEach((key, value) {
      if (value != null && (value is! String || value.trim().isNotEmpty)) {
        result.add('$key=${value.toString()}');
      }
    });
  }

  return result.join('&');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my own function that will escape the parameters that have null value

```
String generateQueryString(Map<String, dynamic> params) {
    List queryString = [];
    params.forEach((key, value) {
      if (value != null) {
        queryString.add(key + '=' + value.toString());
      }
    });
    return queryString.join('&');
  }

  String query = generateQueryString({
    'CategoryId': '1',
    'MinAmount': 0,
    'MaxAmount': 2012,
    'Quantity': 1,
  });

  print(query); // CategoryId=1&MinAmount=0&MaxAmount=2012&Quantity=1
```